# Matlab imagesc clims to OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv

I am rewriting an application from matlab to C++. The problem is with this line

```
imagesc(proj_data.log_P0,m+s*[-3,3])
```

proj_data.log_P0 is some matrix with float values, so what I did in C++ and OpenCV is normalizing that matrix to values that OpenCV can show (range from 0 to 1). That part is working but the part that is making the problem is the clims (bolded) part    imagesc(proj_data.log_P0,**m+s*[-3,3]**). As I understood the clims part is changing the range of colormap, is there any way to do this in OpenCV? It is a grayscale image.

Comment: You should probably post this as an answer and accept it, or delete the question altogether...

Comment: I wasn't able to do it right away, did it now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Before doing the normalization I just found all the matrix elements larger than m+s*3 and changed them to m+s*3, and all the elements smaller than m+s*-3 and changed them to m+s*-3. After doing this with the matrix elements I did the normalization to range from 0 to 1. Same result like in MATLAB's imagesc with clims.